# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end before_action :authenticate_user! except: [:index, :show] ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please i have been trying to connect to my local host and it gives me that @title. This is my code below: The red line indicates the line 3 authenticate. What could b the problem

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! except: [:index, :show]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have missed a ',' before except: [:index, :show]

It should be like below.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed ',' after authenticate_user! so Replace This Line

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```